# Custom log rotation in Django

Tags: django, logging

I want to implement logging in Django such that:

1] After a log file size exceeds a certain threshold, a new log file is generated and written into.
2] The name of this new file should be customisable. As an example, the log file name could be current_date_and_time-app_name.log
3] [Optional] The file that has reached the size limit is zipped and stored.

Note that old log files will never be rewritten as we are creating the new log file with its name as the time at which it is created.
How do I go about doing this?

I tried using the RotatingFileHandler class but it rewrites old logs and also does not give the flexibility to change the log name. Here is the code that I have written:

```
BASE_DIR_APP = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
DIR_LOGS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR_APP, 'logs')
current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%b-%d-%Y_%H-%M-%S--%f")


U_LOGFILE_SIZE = 1 * 1024
U_LOGFILE_COUNT = 2


logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'console': {
            'format': '%(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'
        },
        'file': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'console'
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'file',
            'maxBytes': U_LOGFILE_SIZE,
            'backupCount': U_LOGFILE_COUNT,
            'filename': os.path.join(DIR_LOGS, current_time + '.log')
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console', 'file']
        }
    }
})
```